# quicksort implementation bug java

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

What am I doing wrong in my quicksort implementation below:

```
public static void quicksort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        int pIndex = partition(array, start, end);
        quicksort(array, start, pIndex - 1);
        quicksort(array, pIndex + 1, end);
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = array[end];
    int pIndex = start;
    for (int i = start; i <= end - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] <= pivot) {
            int tmp = array[pIndex];  // swap values
            array[pIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
            pIndex++;
        }
    }
    int tmpVal = array[pIndex];
    array[pIndex] = pivot;
    array[end] = tmpVal;
    return pIndex;
}
```

When running this against the test case of an array {7, 5, 3, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4}, it rearranges the array into {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 6} where it orders the left side of the array, but then enters what seems to be an infinite loop with the array of {1, 2} and never leaving that recursive call. I've tried adding a base case of if the array.length is less than 2, then return; but that makes no difference.

Here's a link to my [code](https://ideone.com/gQv8Gv).

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Are we bound to use your existing code, or can we throw it away and start over fresh?

Comment: My existing code since we're trying to debug this implementation XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= end - 1; i++) {
```

Within `partition` should be

```
for (int i = start; i <= end - 1; i++) {
```

With out this your pIndex can be outside of the range `start` to `end` and there for your recusive calls to quicksort will have the same parameters.

## Edit

Another problem with your ideone code which is not shown above is

```
if (array.length < 2) { return; }
```

Within `quicksort` you are not changing the length of your array so `array.length` will always be 8.

A 3rd problem, and the one causing the infinite loop is

```
while (start < end) {
```

within `quicksort` you are not changing the values for start or end during this loop, so this loop will never exit. see https://ideone.com/wY23C6 for a working example.

Comment: That didn't fix the error, it still loops in the same place, i edited in my linked code. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (start < end) {
    int pIndex = partition(array, start, end);
    quicksort(array, start, pIndex - 1);
    quicksort(array, pIndex + 1, end);
}
```

should be

```
if (start < end) {
    int pIndex = partition(array, start, end);
    quicksort(array, start, pIndex - 1);
    quicksort(array, pIndex + 1, end);
}
```